# What is the style used in ISO/IEC publications?

Tags: style, technical-writing, resources

I'm in the process of preparing a document to be sent to [ISO/IEC WG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/).  What is the official style used in ISO/IEC publications (if there is one)?  If there is no official style guide, is there a standard style guide that closely matches [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)?

Comment: Of course there's a standard... it's ISO! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just quick check on google popped this result:

http://www.iso.org/iso/standards_development/processes_and_procedures/deliverables/iso_guide.htm